# What is the best place to ask why Google released Guava?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I was just thinking the other day - and I thought "Why did Google release [Guava](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava)?"

Business, code, any reason whatsoever - is Stack Overflow the best place (or at least, a reasonable place) to ask such a question, or is it on another Stack Exchange site? And if so, which?

Comment: Stack Overflow is **not** the place as it's not related to any code.

Comment: Google cafeteria.

Comment: Seriously, though, you'd have to ask someone at Google. We're not mind-readers and, if they've blogged about it, you can find the blog as easily as we can. There is not a place in the Stack Exchange network where this would be an appropriate question.

Comment: @AlEverett You should post that as an answer, as it is the answer.

Comment: @Servy: Okay, if you insist.

Answer (score 13):

Chat would be the place to take a question like this. It's short and self contained and you'd get plenty of opinions from folks that know something about it.

Still, unless you asked the people at Google directly, that's all you're really getting - educated guesses, even if obviousness points at them being correct.

It's not inconceivable that someone from Google would answer your question if you asked it, but it's not really about programming or an actual / theoretical problem that you face. It's more about strategy and the business of software and we don't *yet* have a site for that.

Chat is really good for these interesting questions that are tangentially related to the topic of a site, but not quite *on* topic for the site.

Answer (score 5):

You'd have to ask someone at Google. We're not mind-readers and, if they've blogged about it, you can find the blog as easily as we can.

There is not a place in the Stack Exchange network where this would be an appropriate question

Answer (score 2):

Just to share my thoughts, for good or for bad: I think the reasoning is the same as the reasoning why Stack Exchange released their API.

Taken from the [user guide](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained):

> The Guava project contains several of Google's core libraries that we rely on in our Java-based projects: collections, caching, primitives support, concurrency libraries, common annotations, string processing, I/O, and so forth. Each of these tools really do get used every day by Googlers, in production services.